# ASP.NET Ajax Serialize Form & Prevent default submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to serialize form data and bind it to the model parameter of my controller actionresult. For some reason I cannot prevent the default submit produced by the jquery/javascript below. You can see that i put multiple e.preventDefault()s .. Obviously I'd only need to use the 1st one (if it worked), but NONE of them work. The Form fully submits everytime, so the .done() part of my ajax call is never run.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.save-attendance-record-button').click(function() {

    $('#form-edit-attendance-record').submit();

    $('#form-edit-attendance-record').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'html',
            method: 'post',
            url: resolveUrl('~/Home/EditAttendanceRecord'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#attendance-records-partial').html(data);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
});


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditAttendanceRecord(AttendanceRecord record)
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: are you sending it in json? or xml?

Comment: @Aravind whatever the default is, i assume thats XML? thats not really the point though. The point is that the form is doing a full submit INSTEAD of using my ajax request. Thats why I need to prevent the default submit

Comment: you're defining the submit handler after you call submit.

Comment: `$('#form-edit-attendance-record').submit();` what does this line says?

Comment: `$('#form-edit-attendance-record').submit();` triggers submitting process [Docs states](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) look at 3rd overload. On click you have to serialize the form and make ajax request only, do not call submit.